# identity and rectify port scanning activities on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, malware, port-scanning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

My Linux (CentOS 5.x) machine seem to have been attacked. Port scanning activities were traced to it. However, the ports (to be) scanned were only 8080. As a temporary measure, I have updated the iptables rules to drop all outbound traffic from the machine to port 8080.

However, 
1. I would like to ascertain if indeed my machine has been compromised. 
2. Also if it is really port scanning, would it be restricted to just a single port 8080? 
3. And most importantly, should the machine be infected with some malware, causing the port scans, how please can I make it clean again.

Thanks

Comment: I know this may not seem like a "duplicate" of the question we've linked it to, but the steps are the same -- Your machine is doing something it shouldn't be, so assume it's compromised and work from there.  Re: only scanning port 8080, that's often considered an "interesting" port (admin panels are run there frequently, some proxy servers listen on that port, etc.) -- Definitely on the list of ports that I would scan if I were snooping around :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a many different ways an attacker could be using your system to attack other sites, I'll cover a couple of the more common ones.

**Someone has gained remote shell access to your system.**

This can happen with a weak SSH password, poor firewall rules or exploitable programs running on your server.  The first thing I would check is (with the `iptables` block removed for a short period) is the output of `netstat -anp`.  If you see suspicious outbound tcp/8080 connections, grab the PID from the last column and see what process they are originating.

If the offending process is `httpd`, `nginx`, etc. proceed to the next section, otherwise you should take a look at this question:

[How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

**Someone is exploiting a script you have hosted by your webserver.**

If the offending process is a webserver, or something like FastCGI this is likely the case.  This is very common with PHP and Perl::CGI, but can happen with any language of course.  A script you are using is written poorly, or the version of Perl/PHP/etc. is vulnerable to an attack.  You can use the access logs (e.g. `/var/log/httpd/access_log`) to see which script is being repeatedly hit (and from where!) and remove or fix it.

In any event, you should patch your server regularly as well.